# WPF combobox in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

This is an example exhibiting the behaviour I'm having trouble with. I have a datagrid which is bound to an observable collection of records in a viewmodel. In the datagrid I have a DataGridTemplateColumn holding a combobox which is populated from a list in the viewmodel. The datagrid also contains text columns. There are some textboxes at the bottom of the window to show the record contents.

```
<Window x:Class="Customer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Customer"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SelectedRowConverter x:Key="selectedRowConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgCustomers" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding customers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow,
                    Converter={StaticResource selectedRowConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  CanUserAddRows="True" Grid.Row="0" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Country">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cmbCountry" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.countries,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedValuePath="name" Margin="5"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedCountry,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Mode=TwoWay,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="cmbCountry_SelectionChanged" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}" Width="1*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone" Binding="{Binding phone}" Width="1*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Grid x:Name="grdDisplay" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=dgCustomers}" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Country:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="4" Content="Code:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <BulletDecorator  Grid.Column="0">
                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <Label Content="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtId" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgCustomers, Path=SelectedItem.name}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
            </BulletDecorator>
            <BulletDecorator Grid.Column="1">
                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <Label Content="Code:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtCode" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgCustomers, Path=SelectedItem.countryCode}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
            </BulletDecorator>
            <BulletDecorator Grid.Column="2">
                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <Label  Content="Phone:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtPhone" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgCustomers, Path=SelectedItem.phone}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
            </BulletDecorator>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Initially there are no records so the datagrid is empty and shows just one line containing the combobox. If the user enters data into the text columns first then a record is added to the collection and the combobox value can be added to the record. However, if the user selects the combobox value first, then the value disappears when another column is selected. How do I get the combobox data added to the record if it is selected first?

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public GridModel gridModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        gridModel = new GridModel();
        //dgCustomers.DataContext = gridModel;
        this.DataContext = gridModel;
    }

    private void cmbCountry_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox c = sender as ComboBox;
        Debug.Print("ComboBox selection changed, index is " + c.SelectedIndex + ", selected item is " + c.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

The Record class:

```
public class Record : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }

    private string _phone;
    public string phone
    {
        get { return _phone; }
        set
        {
            _phone = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("phone");
        }
    }

    private int _countryCode;
    public int countryCode
    {
        get { return _countryCode; }
        set
        {
            _countryCode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("countryCode");
        }
    }
}
```

Country class:

```
public class Country : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }

    private int _id;
    public int id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("id");
        }
    }

    private int _code;
    public int code
    {
        get { return _code; }
        set
        {
            _code = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("code");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _name;
    }
}
```

GridModel:

```
public class GridModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Record> customers { get; set; }
    public List<Country> countries { get; set; }
    public GridModel()
    {
        customers = new ObservableCollection<Record>();
        countries = new List<Country> { new Country { id = 1, name = "England", code = 44 }, new Country { id = 2, name = "Germany", code = 49 },
        new Country { id = 3, name = "US", code = 1}, new Country { id = 4, name = "Canada", code = 11 }};
    }

    private Country _selectedCountry;
    public Country SelectedCountry
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCountry;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedCountry = value;
            _selectedRow.countryCode = _selectedCountry.code;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRow");
        }
    }

    private Record _selectedRow;
    public Record SelectedRow
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedRow;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedRow = value;
            Debug.Print("Datagrid selection changed"); 
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRow");
        }
    }
}
```

Converters:

```
class Converters
{
}

public class SelectedRowConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Record)
            return value;
        return new Customer.Record();
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModelBase()
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping!

***EDIT*** Thanks for the help Mark, I'm running the code you provided in your answer below, but I'm still not getting a country code in the text box at the bottom of the window. I'm getting these errors:

> ***System.Windows.Data Error: 23*** : Cannot convert '{NewItemPlaceholder}' from type 'NamedObject' to type 'CustomersFreezable.RecordViewModel' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter cannot convert from MS.Internal.NamedObject.
>      at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
>      at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
>      at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)'
>
> ***System.Windows.Data Error: 7*** : ConvertBack cannot convert value '{NewItemPlaceholder}' (type 'NamedObject'). BindingExpression:Path=SelectedRow; DataItem='GridModel' (HashCode=62992796); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name='dgCustomers'); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter cannot convert from MS.Internal.NamedObject.
>      at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
>      at MS.Internal.Data.ObjectTargetConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
>   Datagrid selection changed
>   Datagrid selection changed
>
> ***System.Windows.Data Error: 40*** : BindingExpression path error: 'countryCode' property not found on 'object' ''RecordViewModel' (HashCode=47081572)'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem.countryCode; DataItem='DataGrid' (Name='dgCustomers'); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='txtCode'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
>
> ***System.Windows.Data Error: 23*** : Cannot convert '{NewItemPlaceholder}' from type 'NamedObject' to type 'CustomersFreezable.RecordViewModel' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter cannot convert from MS.Internal.NamedObject.
>      at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
>      at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
>      at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)'
>
> ***System.Windows.Data Error: 7*** : ConvertBack cannot convert value '{NewItemPlaceholder}' (type 'NamedObject'). BindingExpression:Path=SelectedRow; DataItem='GridModel' (HashCode=62992796); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name='dgCustomers'); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter cannot convert from MS.Internal.NamedObject.
>      at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
>      at MS.Internal.Data.ObjectTargetConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
>   Datagrid selection changed
>
> ***System.Windows.Data Error: 40*** : BindingExpression path error: 'countryCode' property not found on 'object' ''RecordViewModel' (HashCode=47081572)'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem.countryCode; DataItem='DataGrid' (Name='dgCustomers'); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='txtCode'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

I've tried to address the BindingExpression path error by altering the static resource:

```
<local:BindingProxy x:Key="CountryProxy" Data="{Binding}" />
```

and therefore the ItemsSource of the DataGrid:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=CountryProxy}, Path=Data.countries}" DisplayMemberPath="name"
```

and the binding of the textbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtCode" Text="{Binding Path=record.countryCode}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
```

That gets rid of the Error 40 but still I'm not seeing anything in the textbox. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forgive me for being honest but there are many things wrong with this code.

First of all there are some serious deviations from MVVM. MVVM is a layered architecture...first there's the model, then the view model on top, then the view on top of that. Converters are technically part of the view but if anything they are on the other side of the view than the view models. What you're doing is using a converter to generate new records in what effectively should be your model:

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is Record)
        return value;
    return new Customer.Record(); <<<<<<<< this here
}
```

Any time you have converters working directly with non-view classes it's a good indication that your view model isn't doing its job properly, and it almost always leads to broken bindings and buggy behavior.

Another problem is that your Record class looks like it was intended to be the model, namely because it has an integer code for the country instead of a reference to an instance of the Country class. Yet this class is being derived from ViewModelBase and does property change notification. Furthermore the one field that is of type Country (i.e. SelectedCountry in your GridModel) is being bound to by all your records, so changing the country code for one changes them all!

To answer your specific question though, the problem was that DataGrid doesn't create a new record until it detects that one of the fields has been edited. In this case your binding to the SelectedRow wasn't in the record itself, so the record wasn't being created and the value wasn't being propagated through.

Here's a fixed version that adheres to MVVM a bit better and fixes the binding issues:

```
// record model
public class Record
{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public int countryCode {get; set;}
}

// record view model
public class RecordViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Record record = new Record();

    public string name
    {
        get { return record.name; }
        set
        {
            record.name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }

    public string phone
    {
        get { return record.phone; }
        set
        {
            record.phone = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("phone");
        }
    }

    private Country _country;
    public Country country
    {
        get { return _country; }
        set
        {
            _country = value;
            record.countryCode = value.code;
            RaisePropertyChanged("country");
        }
    }

}

public class Country : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }

    private int _id;
    public int id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("id");
        }
    }

    private int _code;
    public int code
    {
        get { return _code; }
        set
        {
            _code = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("code");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _name;
    }
}

public class GridModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<RecordViewModel> customers { get; set; }
    public List<Country> countries { get; set; }

    public GridModel()
    {
        customers = new ObservableCollection<RecordViewModel>();
        countries = new List<Country> { new Country { id = 1, name = "England", code = 44 }, new Country { id = 2, name = "Germany", code = 49 },
    new Country { id = 3, name = "US", code = 1}, new Country { id = 4, name = "Canada", code = 11 }};
    }

    private RecordViewModel _selectedRow;
    public RecordViewModel SelectedRow
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedRow;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedRow = value;
            Debug.Print("Datagrid selection changed");
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedRow");
        }
    }
}

// this is needed for when you need to bind something that isn't part of the visual tree (i.e. your combobox dropdowns)
// see http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/ for details
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="CountryProxy" Data="{Binding Path=countries}" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgCustomers" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding customers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}"
          CanUserAddRows="True" Grid.Row="0" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Country"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=CountryProxy}, Path=Data}" DisplayMemberPath="name"
                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding country, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" /> 
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="1*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone" Binding="{Binding phone, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="1*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <Grid x:Name="grdDisplay" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Country:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="4" Content="Code:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <BulletDecorator  Grid.Column="0">
            <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <Label Content="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtId" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedRow.name}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
        </BulletDecorator>
        <BulletDecorator Grid.Column="1">
            <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <Label Content="Code:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtCode" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedRow.country.code}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
        </BulletDecorator>
        <BulletDecorator Grid.Column="2">
            <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <Label  Content="Phone:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtPhone" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedRow.phone}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
        </BulletDecorator>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Forget the converter, you don't need it. The one problem this code does introduce is that you now need to click on the combo box twice: first to select the row and then again to edit it. But there are plenty of places around the net showing how to fix that so I'll leave it to you.

Comment: Any criticism is appreciated when it is so constructive :) I'm running the code you sent but still I don't see the countryCode in the text box in the bottom of the window. There are a couple of errors in the output window; I have edited the question to add them.

Comment: Sorry, the binding for country code wasn't correct, I fixed it in the XAML above. Another thing I noticed is that those fields at the bottom are binding directly to the elements. While this does usually work you'll find you'll have less problems down the road if you bind to the view model fields instead (which I've now changed that code to do), particularly if you start moving the XAML around or if you need to put breakpoints in the code to make sure the controls are working properly.

Comment: One last thing...the country code edit field at the bottom currently displays the country code correctly but editing it won't propagate back to the record, this is basically a side effect of using a combo box in the datagrid but a country code down below. If you do need this functionality then you'll need to add a countryCode field to the view model. This raises the question of how the view models get the array of countries in the first place...that can be done by having GridModel watch for new RecordViewModels being added to the ObservableCollection and initializing them as they're created.

Comment: doh...there was also a small bug in the RecordViewModel's Country setter: I was calling RaisePropertyChanged on "countryCode" instead of "country".

Comment: And it works! Brilliant, thanks Mark. Those boxes at the bottom were only for me to be able to see what was going on, they don't appear in my actual application. Also thanks for setting me on the path of correct MVVM implementation :)